# Use Jade to dynamically fill a bootstrap caraousel. Some issues on iteration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I am trying to create a boostrap carousel using jade to dynamically iterate through a list of objects and display them in the carousel.

- My first question is obviously is this possible.
- Secondly how might I go about accomplishing it.

Here is a snippet of my code where I am trying to generate the list containing the data-slide-to to element of my carousel :

```
10 - var n = 0
11   while n < newsarticles.length
12       if n == 0
13           li.active(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to="n++")  
14       else
15          li(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to="n++")
```

I know this is bad code but I am failing and finding a reference on how to accomplish this if it is possible.

The error it is throwing is

```
"unexpected text " pointing to line 13
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciate. Thank you for you time in advance and if there is any more information I can provide that would be helpful please let me know.

Here is a full working example of my dynamic carousel code:

```
    extends layout

    block content
        div.container
            #header-carousel.carousel.slide(data-ride="carousel",data-interval="4000")
                ol.carousel-indicators
                    -var n = 0
                        while n < newsarticles.length
                            if n == 0
                                li.active(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to=n)
                                - n++   
                            else
                                li(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to=n)
                                - n++
                .carousel-inner
                    -var i = 0
                    - for newsarticle in newsarticles
                        if i == 0
                            .item.active
                                img(src='#{newsarticle.imgurl}')
                                .carousel-caption #{newsarticle.articletitle}
                            -i++
                        else
                            .item
                                img(src='#{newsarticle.imgurl}')
                                .carousel-caption #{newsarticle.articletitle}
                            -i++

                a.left.carousel-control(href="#header-carousel", data-slide="prev")
                    span.icon-prev
                a.right.carousel-control(href="#header-carousel", data-slide="next")
                    span.icon-next
```

the data associated with this code is as follows:

```
    newsarticle = 
    {  
      articletitle: String,
      bodytext: String,
      editedon: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      imgurl: String
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess issue would be the string you have `n++` increment value in quotes.

i guess you can use a variable for it and then assign it to the data attribute.

Comment: I agree. I have tried it as well with 
        data-slide-to=n++ 
without quotations and I am receiving the exact same message.

Comment: @zzrot okay wait i will let you know the solution for this issue.

Comment: ty @Jai I will continue looking as well. Will keep you updated if I obtain solution.

Comment: Hey @Jai you were partially very correct. I have posted my running code and explanation to here as well. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have arrived at a working solution. Thank you everyone for taking a look. The way I achieved what I was attempting to do was by using @Jai's  advice along with a little external thinking on my own. The issue was definanly the "" around the n++ but it was also trying to increment the variable n inside of the data-slide-to element. If you remove the quotations around it and then increment the variable n separately it works properly. Here is the working version of the code. Also if this is not the best industry practice and there is a better method of accomplishing this I am open to more solutions.

```
    -var n = 0
            while n < newsarticles.length
                if n == 0
                    li.active(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to=n)
                        - n++   
                else
                    li(data-target="#header-carousel",data-slide-to=n)
                        - n++
```